# Multilevel regression meta-analysis in R: no existing package?

Tags: r

The question is in the title.

**Meta-analysis with binomial distribution**

I'm trying to do a meta-analysis on occurence of an event across different studies. For each study $i$ ($i=1,\dots,N$), I have the number of participants $n_i$ and the number of events $k_i$. I don't have individual data. The number of event thus follows a binomial distribution: $k_i\sim Bin(\theta_i,n_i)$, where I assume a random effect: $\theta_i\sim N(\theta,\tau)$.

**Regression meta-analysis**

Additionally, I'm doing a regression on $\theta$ using the variable $x_i$: $$\theta_i\sim N(\alpha+\beta x_i,\tau).$$

**Multi-level regression meta-analysis**

Some studies are split into groups. As they have the same baseline characteristics, I thought of using a multi-level model (first formulation):
$$\theta_{i,j}\sim N(\alpha+\beta x_{i,j},\tau+\delta_j).$$
We could alternatively write it like this (although it is a bit different, second formulation):
$$\theta_{i}\sim N(\alpha+\beta x_i,\tau).$$
$$\theta_{i,j}\sim N(\theta_i+\gamma_i x_{ij},\delta_j)$$

**Which function to use in R**

I thought of doing it with the `rma.mv()` function from the `metareg` package, but the issue is that you cannot specify the distribution of the data. As far as I understood, it assumes normally distributed data. I thought of applying a logit transformation to the probability of success $p_i:=k_i/n_i$, but it's not possible to the some zero counts ($y_i=0$ for some studies i). Any other function that could solve that?
Moreover, I'm not sure if such models follow my first or second formulation.

Comment: Both the question and the use of MathTeX in your text suggests this needs to be on CrossValidated. (Okay, the content ... the MathTeX just demonstrates your exposure on other SE sites :-) Specifically, when you suggest taking the logit transform and calculating `P_s`, that to means sounds like the math-behind-the-programming, so I'm voting to migrate. (If you're asking us to recommend a package, well, idk off the top of my head ... and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Good luck.)

Comment: I already posted on cross validated and was closed because of off topic... I just resubmitted again.

Comment: Haha! I don't know how to help. I can't imagine why this is more appropriate for SO than CV ... in fact, none of the other SE sites I read would be better than CV, specifically the logic/p_s/... discussion. Sorry, I'm out of ideas :-(